# Outlook Appointment - ItemChange and ItemRemove Event

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to sync appointment items from one Calendar to another. I implemented a ItemChange Handler which updates the Appointments based on a specific UserProperty. Now I thought when I delete an Appointment the ItemRemove Event gets fired and I can handle the removal in the other calendars there, but as a matter of fact, the ItemChange Event gets fired first.

How can I check if the passed item was removed, so that I can ignore this case in the ItemChange Handler? I tried to check for Null, Nothing or Empty, but the Item Object is an Appointment, where as most of the properties (EntryId, UserProperies,...) result in an error.

Here is some simplified code, which should help to understand my question

```
 Private Sub newCal_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
  Dim appointment As Outlook.appointmentItem
  Set appointment = Item
  If (appointment <> deleted) Then
   ' update other calendars
  Else
   ' do nothing and proceed with ItemRemove Event
  End If
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy: just use the event  _ItemAdd  BUT on the trash folder!!
e.g.

```
Private WithEvents trashCalendar1 As Outlook.Items
...
Private Sub trashCalendar1_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set objNS = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim result As Boolean
    '
    result = ...'here the actual boolean sync removing function on calendar2
                'where you'd use your custom userproperty to find the item to delete 
                'in the calendar2-related folder
    If result Then
      MsgBox "sync removed"
    End If
End Sub
```